# c - segmentation fault storing input to and adding two pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting segmentations fault while doing this, compiler does not show any error though.
Forgive me if I'm asking very basic question, because I have not been good at coding in C and its a long time.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct link_list {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct link_list *next;
    struct link_list *prev;
};

int inp_sum (int *x, int *y){
        printf("Enter x:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("Enter y:");
        scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d+%d",x,y);
    int z;
    z=*x+*y;
    return z;
}

void main(){
    struct link_list *first_node;
    first_node=malloc(sizeof(struct link_list));
    first_node->next=0;
    first_node->prev=0;

    struct link_list *cur;
    cur = malloc(sizeof(struct link_list));
    while(inp_sum(&cur->x,&cur->y)<100){
        cur->next=malloc(sizeof(struct link_list));
        cur=cur->next;
        cur->next=0;
        cur->prev=0;
    }

    print_llist(first_node);
}

print_llist(struct link_list *root){
    struct link_list *current;
    current=malloc(sizeof(struct link_list));
    current = root;
    while ( current != NULL ) {
        printf( "%d\n", current->x );
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

what I want to do is create a link list node and extend the link list if sum of inputs is less than 100, for that I want to send pointers of x,y(members of node) to a function which returns their sum after taking input and storing the input to them.

But I think I'm doing this wrong while passing the pointers or adding the pointers.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` are already pointers, so this:

```
    printf("Enter x:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    //         ^ address of int *
    printf("Enter y:");
    scanf("%d",&y);
```

//         ^ address of int *

should be:

```
    printf("Enter x:");
    scanf("%d",x);
    //         ^ address of int
    printf("Enter y:");
    scanf("%d",y);
    //         ^ address of int
```

In the code you wrote, you read into the int pointer, e.g. override the address of the int, and then dereference it (in the addition) which causes segmentation fault.

Comment: that solved the segmentation problem, but now I couldnt add the pointers, theres error that `invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’` can you please help me with that.

Comment: From your comment I assumed you tried to do `z=x+y;` which is adding to pointers, which is invalid, ou should still dereference them: `z=*x+*y;`

Comment: I did that first then I got this output `Enter x:2
Enter y:3
37281808+37281812Enter x:
`

Comment: then I thought I might be adding adress or something like that, so I removed the `*`

Comment: Sorry!! It worked I was printing the address not adding the adresses! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors you might want to correct.

** The scanf parts are making some troubles here. They should be like

```
scanf("%d",x);
scanf("%d",y);
```

** Your`first_node` should be connected to something. I'm assuming that it is a dummy head. So after introducing your `cur` node, you should have `first_node->next = cur`

** Each node in this linked list is not connected to anything. You should have these in your main function:

```
while(inp_sum(&cur->x,&cur->y)<100){
    cur->next=malloc(sizeof(struct link_list));
    struct link_list *temp = cur;
    cur=cur->next;
    cur->next=0;
    cur->prev=temp;
}
```